# my http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js twitter widget stopped

Tags: php, twitter

i'm using this code since a while to embed any twitter account tweets in any website , also i use php to get the twitter account name from a mysql database

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
                    <script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 6,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 172,
  height: 205,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#82cbed'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().setUser('<?php echo $twitter_is; ?>').start();
            </script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're probably hitting the twitter widget rate limiting, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206398/caching-api-twitter-calls-for-twitter-profile-widget

Comment: <?php echo $twitter_is; ?> is very in-secure, imagine if that variable was `');alert("Hi");/*`, your application would break

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with shofnee.

Twitter have discontinued their old API as of June 11th 2013 which appears to have stopped your code working (I am in a similar position). Further information can be found https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Comment: Yep this is the problem. It has been discontinued. Have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read an example in - https://twitter.com/javascripts/widgets/widget.js
May be it'll help

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get something similar wired up again, check out this how-to from the Twitter developer blog.

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/embedded-timelines-howto